# PHPMyAdmin - Update 30k rows with looped number sequence

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I hope i'm explaining this properly... but i'm trying to update a column in a table with 30k rows with a repeated sequence.

I've populated entire columns before with random numbers using:

UPDATE locations SET template = CAST((RAND() * 4)+1 AS UNSIGNED);

Which gave:

- 2
- 4
- 5
- 1
- 3

etc. in a random fashion throughout the 30k rows...

I would like to enter a query that can produce a repeated sequence like:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

across all 30k rows.

I've been looking into loops and auto increments but can't get it to work.

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: Did u try to add a integer column which is autoincrement?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a variable will do for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(ID INT, SEQNO INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,NULL),(2,NULL),(3,NULL),(4,NULL),(5,NULL),(6,NULL),(7,NULL);

UPDATE  T
SET SEQNO = (SELECT IF(@RN = 2 ,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN + 1) FROM (SELECT @RN:=0) R)
WHERE 1 = 1

+------+-------+
| ID   | SEQNO |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     1 |
|    2 |     2 |
|    3 |     1 |
|    4 |     2 |
|    5 |     1 |
|    6 |     2 |
|    7 |     1 |
+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions... I had a hard time finding an answer but eventually found something that would do exactly what I was after. I must admit it is far beyond my capabilities, but here it is:

```html
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @max_num = 75;
update locations loc1
join (
    select 
        if ((num % @max_num) = 0, @max_num, (num % @max_num)) as num2,
        a.*    
    from (
        select 
        (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
        loc.* 
        from locations loc  
        ORDER BY num
    ) a
    order by num, num2
) loc2 on (loc2.id = loc1.id)
set loc1.colname = loc2.num2;
```